# Cant get value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, getelementbyid, element

I try to get input value of my form. I already try many solutions but still no results. Here is form input:

```
 <input class="form-control" id="account_ya_price_list_url shop_key_input" name="account[ya_price_list_url]" type="text" style="/* margin-right: 20px; */">
```

Js:

```
    console.log($('#shop_key_input').html());
    console.log($('#shop_key_input').val());
    console.log($('#shop_key_input').value);
    var div = document.getElementById('shop_key_input');
    var div2 = document.getElementsByName('account[ya_price_list_url]').first;
    console.log(div2.innerHTML );
    console.log(div.innerHTML );
    console.log(div2.value );
    console.log(div.value );
```

All of this or undefined or null. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to have confused the `id` and `class` attributes; an `id` (if present) must have only *one* attribute-value (no white-space), and a `class` can take a white-space separated *list* of attribute-values.

Comment: @DavidThomas, you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of the `id` attribute needs to be *an id* not a space separated list of ids (it does not work like the `class` attribute).

```
id="account_ya_price_list_url shop_key_input"
```

should be

```
id="shop_key_input"
```

then `#shop_key_input` will match it.

Answer (score 0):

Only one `ID` is allowed per element.

So try using just `#shop_key_input` and using either
  `document.getElementById('shop_key_input');` or     `$('#shop_key_input')`

Answer (score -2):

use class to get the value of textbox

```
  $('.form-control').val();
```